# Evaluating $\int_{-2}^2 \frac{\sqrt{4-\epsilon ^2} }{1-\beta \epsilon ^2} e^{-i t \epsilon }\mathrm{d}\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I encountered this integral

$$\int_{-2}^2 \frac{\sqrt{4-\epsilon ^2} }{1-\beta  \epsilon ^2} e^{-i t \epsilon }\mathrm{d}\epsilon$$

where $\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ and $t\in \mathbb{R}^+$.

Any hint on how to perform this integral?

Comment: try to expand $e^{i(-t\epsilon)}$ using Euler’s formula?

Comment: Well that doesn't seem to lead anywhere. The sin part vanishes so you are left with $\cos(\epsilon t)$ and then there does not seem to be a way around it

Comment: Where did you come across this integral? On the internet, an exam,  thought of it on your own, etc.?

Comment: It is a result of some long calculation in physics. It is the final result for how some quantity of interest decays in time as a function of model parameter beta.

Comment: Comment:

Substitute $\epsilon=2x$ to get
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{4-4x^2}}{1-4\beta x^2}\mathrm e^{-\mathrm it~2x}\cdot 2\mathrm dx$$
Letting $b^2=4\beta,$ $a=2t$ consider
$$F(a,b)=\int_{-1}^1 \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-b^2x^2}\mathrm e^{-\mathrm iax}\mathrm dx=\int_{-1}^1 \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-b^2x^2}\mathrm \cos(ax)\mathrm dx$$

In the case of $b=1$ this is nothing but $\pi J_0(a)$, but I'm not sure what to do in the case of general $b$.

Comment: I **doubt** there's a **closed-form** for the integral for the general parameter $\beta$.